# Creating a Django sign up form with two password inputs only one of which is sent to the database

Tags: python, django, forms

I wanted to create a sign up page with two inputs for a password, to see if they match and then input only one final password into the database.

I have seen people suggest putting in two separate password fields: a `'password1'` and `'password2'`. Then creating a form with these two fields and then checking if the two match one another.

However I wanted to know if there was a way I could create a model class with just one `'password'` field and still create a form with two inputs that will check if both inputs match. Then return only one password to the `'password'` field in the database.

I am new to Django and programming in general. 
Your help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why not use the [`UserCreationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) which does exactly this?

Comment: Thank you for your speedy comment. I will look into it, @little_birdie also told me I could use it as a guide to create my own form. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing User model that's part of django's contrib.auth module stores passwords as a hash value.. and provides a function for setting the password:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#methods

They also provide a UserCreationForm class to go with the model that does exactly what you are asking.  If their form doesn't fit in with your plans, you can look at their source code and use it as a guide:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/forms/

But, to answer your question directly:  Let's say you did want to store a cleartext password into your own model, and you did want to make a form for that...  In that case:

It's totally ok to add extra fields to a Modelform subclass of your own.  The form will then contain the fields generated from the model, along with any fields you added.  When the form is saved, your added fields will be ignored..  but you can still access them in form.cleaned_data and write validation methods for them.

So let's say your real model password field is called `password`.. you can add another field to the form called `password_again` and then, create a `clean` method on your form, something like:

```
def clean(self, value):
    cd = self.cleaned_data

    if self._errors:
        return cd

    cd['password'] = cd['password'].strip()
    cd['password_again'] = cd['password_again'].strip()

    if not cd['password']:
        raise ValidationError("Passwords Can't Be Blank")

    if cd['password'] != cd['password_again']:
        raise ValidationError("Passwords Don't Match")

    return cd
```

All that said.. it's not usually a good idea to store cleartext passwords in the database.  Django's authentication system works.. it sometimes takes a little effort to get it to work the way you want, but it's probably easier to modify it to suit your needs (eg. writing your own forms based on their form code, or subclassing their forms to make them behave the way you want) than it is to start from zero.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Can I still use the methods above if I don't want the users having access to the admin page? Should I create my own class in models for storing user data, calling it something other than User?

Comment: Any user can be in the auth system (auth.User model).. only users with the is_staff field set to True will get access to admin.  If you need to store extra fields for each user you can either store them in another model or, if it really makes sense for your applicaiton, you can customize the existing User model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-custom-user-model